# Doing Math with SQL and multiple Conditions

Tags: mysql

Trying to sum a column based on multiple criteria.  Ill try to explain it best I can.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   Store_Location_Code VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
  ,Tradein_Date        VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL
  ,Ship_Date           VARCHAR(9)
  ,Processed_Date      VARCHAR(9)
  ,Model               VARCHAR(44) NOT NULL
  ,Diff                NUMERIC(6,2) NOT NULL
  ,Payment_Amount      VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL
  ,Adjustment_Reason   VARCHAR(180)
);
INSERT INTO mytable(Store_Location_Code,Tradein_Date,Ship_Date,Processed_Date,Model,Diff,Payment_Amount,Adjustment_Reason) VALUES ('80109','8/24/2020','8/27/2020','9/4/2020','APPL A1984 iPhone XR 128GB - VZW',0,'149.10','Device Not Received');
INSERT INTO mytable(Store_Location_Code,Tradein_Date,Ship_Date,Processed_Date,Model,Diff,Payment_Amount,Adjustment_Reason) VALUES ('80109','8/20/2020','8/27/2020','9/3/2020','APPL A1864 iPhone 8 Plus 64GB - SPR',0,'10.00',NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(Store_Location_Code,Tradein_Date,Ship_Date,Processed_Date,Model,Diff,Payment_Amount,Adjustment_Reason) VALUES ('80109','8/21/2020','8/27/2020','9/10/2020','MOTO XT1635-01 Moto Z Play Droid 32GB - VZW',0,'0.00',NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(Store_Location_Code,Tradein_Date,Ship_Date,Processed_Date,Model,Diff,Payment_Amount,Adjustment_Reason) VALUES ('80109','8/23/2020','8/27/2020','9/4/2020','APPL A1660 iPhone 7 128GB - VZW',0,'4.99',NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(Store_Location_Code,Tradein_Date,Ship_Date,Processed_Date,Model,Diff,Payment_Amount,Adjustment_Reason) VALUES ('80109','8/26/2020','8/27/2020','9/5/2020','SAMS SM-G955U Galaxy S8+ 64GB - VZW',0,'59.40',NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(Store_Location_Code,Tradein_Date,Ship_Date,Processed_Date,Model,Diff,Payment_Amount,Adjustment_Reason) VALUES ('80109','9/8/2020','9/11/2020','9/29/2020','APPL A1863 iPhone 8 64GB - VZW',0,'76.08',NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(Store_Location_Code,Tradein_Date,Ship_Date,Processed_Date,Model,Diff,Payment_Amount,Adjustment_Reason) VALUES ('80109','9/7/2020','9/11/2020','9/29/2020','APPL A1863 iPhone 8 256GB - VZW',0,'181.30',NULL);
```

Payment_Amount is the row amount.  Adjustment_Reason is notes.  I want to make it so that if Payment_Amount < 5 then it doesnt do anything but keep original value.  If > 5 then subtract 5 from total of row.  Then the 2nd criteria would be if Adjustment_Reason contains "Did not Receive" then 0 that value.

```
SELECT SUM(Payment_Amount - IF(Payment_Amount > 5.00, 5.00, 0))
FROM mytable
Group By Model;


#if the amount is less than $5 then do not deduct
#anything over $5 should deduct 5 from total
#if reason shows Device Not Received then change amount to 0.00
```

This is what I have so far.  Now What I need is to make value 0 if Adjustment_Reason contains "Device not Received"

[image]

The above for example should be for the first row 4.99 because it is less than 5.00 but the second row should be 176.30.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/196c6f/1

Comment: Sum without a group by clause usually does not make sense. It would be nice to see sample data and expected output, so we can help you with your query. My guess is that you need conditional aggregation, meaning the case statement should be within the sum(): sum(case ... end).

Comment: @Shadow I posted a fiddle with data.  The expected output should be the total Payment_Amount minus $5 unless it is not received which should be 0.  And if the total amount is $5 or less than no deduction.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cef9a90/4

Comment: You're doing some weird mixing of looking at individual records (`WHEN f.Payment_Amount > 5.00`) and aggregating records (`SUM(f.Payment_Amount-5.00)`) in the same expression. This just doesn't make sense. Please describe, as specifically as possible, what you are trying to do. Phrases like _"subtract 5 from total of row"_ don't make sense: usually you total a column, not a row.

Comment: @kmoser Yes I know it seems it doesnt make sense.  But i need to subtract 5 from each record.  Say I get paid 10 dollars... and you helped me so i say ill give you 5.  Then my pay would be 5.  Thats the logic.  I need to subtract $5 from every row value and then sum that total.  So if I have 3 rows that total 30 then the value after calculations should be 15.  I guess I dont know how else to explain that.  Seems pretty straight forward.

Comment: There's no col1 here

Comment: @DavidMorin So far you've described this: `SUM(f.Payment_Amount)`.  But what if the starting amount for a given row is less than 5? Do you still want to subtract 5 from it before adding it to the total? If not, then you'd want: `SUM(f.Payment_Amount - IF(f.Payment_Amount > 5, 5, 0))`.

Comment: @Strawberry clearly the above was an example.  The actual data is in the fiddle.

Comment: @kmoser Then how would I handle ones that show Device Not Received?

Comment: This isn't 'what you have so far'

Comment: And store data using an appropriate data type for that data

Comment: Change to suitable datatypes (away from `VARCHAR`).  Then we can discuss your issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a double IF() test.  If the reason = "Device Not Received", subtract the full payment amount value, anything else, then test if > 5, and if so, subtract 5, all-else, subtract nothing.

```
SELECT SUM(Payment_Amount - if( Adjustment_Reason = 'Device Not Received', 
                                   Payment_Amount,    
                                   IF(Payment_Amount > 5.00, 5.00, 0 )
                              )
          )
FROM mytable
Group By Model;
```

I adjusted your SQLFiddle example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/196c6f/4